# How to get filename from FileChooserButton in PyGTK?

Tags: application-development, python, quickly, pygtk, glade

I'm using Glade and PyGtk to develop an application. Currently I'm using a button under a toolbar to open files using this code:

```
    def on_openVideo_clicked(self, widget):
        dialog = Gtk.FileChooserDialog("Please choose a video", self,
            Gtk.FileChooserAction.OPEN,
            (Gtk.STOCK_CANCEL, Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL,
             Gtk.STOCK_OPEN, Gtk.ResponseType.OK))

        self.add_vfilters(dialog)
        dialog.set_current_folder('/home')  
        response = dialog.run()

        if response == Gtk.ResponseType.OK:
            self.videoInput = dialog.get_preview_filename()
            print "Video file Choosen: ", self.videoInput
        elif response == Gtk.ResponseType.CANCEL:
            print 'Cancel Clicked'           

        dialog.destroy()
```

But I decided to replace it with a FileChooserButton because it has better visualization. But I don't know how to print the file name. I guessed it should be something like this:

```
def on_filechooserbutton_file_set(self, widget):
        print widget.get_filename()
```

But this doesn't work. So my question is how to retrieve filename from filechooserbutton?

Comment: I think this question best fits on [so].

Comment: I actually post same question, but there was no answer. By the way I found the solution and trying to post it as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This piece of code solved the problem and prints the filename as I wished:

```
def on_filechooserbutton_file_set(self, widget):
        self.videoInput = widget.get_filename()
        print "Video file Choosen: ", self.videoInput
```